# Crystal Reports 8.5 error when loading subReport

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, report

I have a VB6 application which prints some reports. One of the reports has subreports inserted by code.

The function who loads the subreports is this:

```
Public Function loadSubreport(destSection As CRAXDRT.Section, ByVal fileName As String, ByVal srLeft As Long, ByVal srTop As Long) As CRAXDRT.Report
        Dim sr As CRAXDRT.SubreportObject
        Set sr = destSection.ImportSubreport(CStr(fileName), CLng(srLeft), CLng(srTop))
        sr.BottomLineStyle = crLSNoLine
        sr.TopLineStyle = crLSNoLine
        sr.LeftLineStyle = crLSNoLine
        sr.RightLineStyle = crLSNoLine
        Set loadSubreport = sr.OpenSubreport
End Function
```

Everything works fine.

But sometimes the line:

```
Set sr = destSection.ImportSubreport(CStr(fileName), CLng(srLeft), CLng(srTop))
```

gives `error: Invaild procedure call or argument`.

If try to print again, it works fine.

I try to add some error handling, to run again the same code and it's still not working.

Anyone has a clue about this one ?

Comment: Maybe a problem in building the report to your Bin.
Try forcing the report to rebuild upon every build of your project.